# Missing in action: Stack Snippet arrow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-snippets

The arrow in front of "Show code snippet" when a snippet is hidden is missing in action.

Example below:

```html
<h1>How it is</h1>

<img id="currenthide" src="http://i.imgur.com/9nW7142.png"><br>
<img id="currentshow" src="http://i.imgur.com/B6ZHGT9.png">

<h1>How it should be</h1>

<img id="futurehide" src="http://i.imgur.com/jFq1SXK.png"><br>
<img id="futureshow" src="http://i.imgur.com/IEE5czm.png">
```

---

This seems to be a problem with the `expander-arrow-hide` and `expander-arrow-show` class. The values for `background-position` are way off. I believe that they should be corrected like this:

```
.expander-arrow-hide {
  background-position: 8px -375px;
}

.expander-arrow-show {
  background-position: -14px -375px;
}
```

Comment: The position actually gets really close if you turn the background-repeat back on. A 870px adjustment on a 500px image is really weird though.

Comment: There's another arrow that went awol.  In the post history view, the one you click to view a post that was collapsed.

Comment: I am assuming those are positions on an old sprite file, and has been changed since the new layout.

Comment: @HansPassant Seems to be the same arrow css-wise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live after our next production build.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously not a final solution, but until it's fixed I've made a user style with the code you provided. [You can find it here.](https://userstyles.org/styles/110106/stack-overflow-arrow-placement-correction)